# Expand Image resize script to .PNG and .GIF

Tags: php, image, resize, gif

I have a script which resizes .JPG images perfectly, it does exactly what it's supposed to do.
However, I want to offer the user the option of also adding .PNG en .GIF images. Can someone help me expand the following script so it also support these formats? Thanks in advance!

```
$image = $_POST['bedrijfslogo'];
$new_image = "../subdomains/{$gemeente7}/httpdocs/{$plaatsnaam7}/{$bedrijfsnaam7}/bedrijfslogo.jpg";
copy($_POST['bedrijfslogo'],"copylogo.jpg");
$width=250; //*** Fix Width & Heigh (Autu caculate) ***//
$size=GetimageSize($image);
$height=round($width*$size[1]/$size[0]);
$images_orig = ImageCreateFromJPEG($image);
$photoX = ImagesX($images_orig);
$photoY = ImagesY($images_orig);
$images_fin = ImageCreateTrueColor($width, $height);
ImageCopyResampled($images_fin, $images_orig, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width+1, $height+1, $photoX, $photoY);
ImageJPEG($images_fin, $new_image);
ImageDestroy($images_orig);
ImageDestroy($images_fin);
unlink($image);
```

Comment: Use [`finfo_file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php) to get the MIME type of the uploaded file, `switch` it and assign a value to `$images_orig` using `imagecreatefrom*()` as appropriate to the MIME type. Or if you're feeling lazy you could safely (but less reliably) just use the file extension to determine which function to use. Aside from that the rest of the script can be left untouched.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, however this script is not mine. I found it on the internet and could edit it to fit my needs. I'm no PHP pro so just a bit more help: what do I do with the ImageJPEG at the last bit of the script?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the type of outputfile you want, add, and select:

```
imagecreatefrompng
```

and

```
 imagecreatefromgif
```

and

```
 imagepng
```

and

```
 imagegif
```

Answer (score 0):

Following my comment I realised you can extract the type of the image from the data returned by `getimagesize()`.

Try this, it should accept any type of image that your PHP instance is capable of understanding (*untested*):

```
// Get file paths
// Taking a local file path direct from the user? This is a *big* security risk...
$srcPath = $_POST['bedrijfslogo'];
$dstPath = "../subdomains/{$gemeente7}/httpdocs/{$plaatsnaam7}/{$bedrijfsnaam7}/bedrijfslogo.jpg";

// Not really sure why this is here, you don't seem to use the copy of the file
copy($srcPath, "copylogo.jpg");

// Get information about source image
$info = getimagesize($srcPath);
$srcWidth = $info[0];
$srcHeight = $info[1];
$srcType = $info[2];

// Calculate new width and height
// Width is fixed, height calculated from width
$dstWidth = 250;
$dstHeight = round($dstWidth * $srcHeight / $srcWidth);

// Get the image types supported by this instance of PHP
$supportedTypes = imagetypes();

// Create the source image resource based on it's type
switch ($srcType) {
  case IMG_GIF:
    if ($supportedTypes & IMG_GIF) {
      $srcImage = imagecreatefromgif($srcPath);
    } else {
      // GIF support not enabled on your PHP instance. Handle error here.
      exit('GIF support not enabled on this PHP instance');
    }
    break;
  case IMG_JPG: case IMG_JPEG: // Think these might have the same value?
    if ($supportedTypes & IMG_JPG) {
      $srcImage = imagecreatefromjpeg($srcPath);
    } else {
      // JPEG support not enabled on your PHP instance. Handle error here.
      exit('JPEG support not enabled on this PHP instance');
    }
    break;
  case IMG_PNG:
    if ($supportedTypes & IMG_PNG) {
      $srcImage = imagecreatefrompng($srcPath);
    } else {
      // PNG support not enabled on your PHP instance. Handle error here.
      exit('PNG support not enabled on this PHP instance');
    }
    break;
  case IMG_WBMP:
    if ($supportedTypes & IMG_WBMP) {
      $srcImage = imagecreatefromwbmp($srcPath);
    } else {
      // WBMP support not enabled on your PHP instance. Handle error here.
      exit('WBMP support not enabled on this PHP instance');
    }
    break;
  case IMG_XPM:
    if ($supportedTypes & IMG_XPM) {
      $srcImage = imagecreatefromxpm($srcPath);
    } else {
      // XPM support not enabled on your PHP instance. Handle error here.
      exit('XPM support not enabled on this PHP instance');
    }
    break;
  default:
    // Unknown input file type. Handle error here. Currently prints some debugging info
    echo 'Unknown input file type';
    var_dump($info);
    exit;
}

// Create the destination image resource
$dstImage = imagecreatetruecolor($dstWidth, $dstHeight);

// Resample source image onto destination image
imagecopyresampled($dstImage, $srcImage, 0, 0, 0, 0, $dstWidth + 1, $dstHeight + 1, $srcWidth, $srcHeight);

// Save new image to disk
imagejpeg($dstImage, $dstPath);

// Destroy resources
imagedestroy($srcImage);
imagedestroy($dstImage);
$srcImage = $dstImage = NULL;

// Remove source image - are you sure you want to do this?
unlink($srcPath);
```

Now, this code seems to be designed to work with a local source image, but the way you are using it suggests you might be getting a URL from the user and downloading a remote image. If this is the case let me know and I will modify this slightly to better suite that purpose.

Comment: This should work like a charm, will test it today. Big thanks DaveRandom. The user can add a photo to their company profile and if the picture meets te requirements it gets uploaded to a temporary folder. We (the adminds) have to approve their profile before it gets processed, so on our approve page I have a few input fields with the 'temp-folder-filepaths' as a value. So I am working with a local file, not directly from the user. Big thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately it's not working as we hoped. When I use a JPG I don't get an error, but it deletes the srcfile as it's supposed to, but doesn't create a new file in the designated folder. If I upload a .PNG it simply states the default 'Unknown Input File type'. When I do these two things with my old script it does work for the .JPG but if I work with a .PNG I just end up with a black image. Thanks!

Comment: @user1555076 `but doesn't create a new file in the designated folder.` - this is my mistake, which has now been corrected in the above code. `If I upload a .PNG it simply states the default 'Unknown Input File type'` - I have edited the above code so it will display some more useful debugging info - can you try again and paste the output you get here?

Comment: Turns out srcType is being comparing to the wrong constants. It should be compared to `IMAGETYPE_XXX` constants instead of `IMG_XXX` constants. If you update all the cases to `IMAGETYPE_XXX` (e.g. `IMAGETYPE_PNG`), it should work.

Answer (score 0):

What changing is,

```
$images_orig = ImageCreateFromJPEG($image); //for jpg
```

You can check ***[here](https://www.php.net/manual-lookup.php?pattern=imageCreateFrom&lang=en&scope=404quickref)*** the documentation

You may also go through **[Some comparisons between ImageMagick and GD](http://www.rubblewebs.co.uk/imagemagick/compair.php)** and **[PHP: ImageMagick - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php)**.

Hope this helps